# How to access DI framework Unity Container outside of composition root

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, singleton, unity-container

I have integrated Unity container for my project snapp which has two folders named Commerce and Order. I have created constructor dependency injection for classes inside Commerce folder, say it has controller, manager and storage class (manager & storage - singleton class). The instance of all the classes inside commerce folder has been resolved inside unity container.

In order folder classes inside it doesnt follow dependency injection pattern and hence they have not been registered inside unity container.

Couple of questions here -

1. how do we access instance of CommerceManager class in OrderManager? I have read about servicelocator to get the unity container but it is mentioned as anti-pattern. please explain the right way of accessing instance here.
2. Eventhough CommerceManager class is a singleton class but we expose public constructor from this class for resolving instances by unity container. How do we ensure that other projects using this as a reference maintains the singleton property of this class?

Comment: Why does "order folder classes" not use dependency injection? That would solve your first question.

Comment: The project snapp has lot of folders one such examples were commerce & order. Adding DI to all the classes will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. how do we access instance of CommerceManager class in OrderManager? I have read about servicelocator to get the unity container but it is mentioned as anti-pattern. please explain the right way of accessing instance here.

I see three options:

1. Dependency injection: take `CommerceManager` as input in the constructor of `OrderManager` or similar depency injection (e.g. method, propterty injection). This has the benefit of streamlining your solution and making your classes easier to unit test.
2. Using the service locator pattern: I think you already know why that's not preferable.
3. Access/instantiate instance itself: if `CommerceManager` is implemented as a singleton you could access the instance directly or if it doesn't need to be a singleton `OrderManager` can instantiate one itself. The benefit is that it's easy. However, unit testing becomes quite tricky if not impossible, because you cannot mock `CommerceManager` as `OrderManager` now has a hard-coded dependency to it.

---

> 2. Eventhough CommerceManager class is a singleton class but we expose public constructor from this class for resolving instances by unity container. How do we ensure that other projects using this as a reference maintains the singleton property of this class?

The only way that's possible is to build `CommerceManager` as a real  singleton class (without public constructor). Right now, it sounds like you let your DI container control the lifecycle of the class. This means, only if you access an instance of `CommerceManager` through your DI container will you use the singleton instance.

If other projects are **not** accessing it through the DI container, you need to control it through the class itself (or some "accessor" class as an intermediate class):

```
public class SingletonCommerceManager
{
    private static Lazy<SingletonCommerceManager> _instance
        = new Lazy<SingletonCommerceManager>(() => new SingletonCommerceManager());
    public static SingletonCommerceManager Instance => _instance.Value;

    private SingletonCommerceManager()
    { /* ... */ }
}


// Or (essentially the same but removing "singleton logic" from CommerceManager)...


// 'internal' to only make it accessible within the assembly
internal class CommerceManager
{
    internal CommerceManager()
    { /* ... */ }
}

// 'public' to make it the only way to access 'CommerceManager' outside the assembly
public class CommerceManagerAccessor
{
    private Lazy<CommerceManager> _singletonInstance
        = new Lazy<CommerceManager>(() => new SingletonCommerceManager());

    public CommerceManager Singleton => _singletonInstance.Value;
}
```

Comment: The CommerceManager class cannot be a Real singleton as the contructor takes DI parameters. Here the singleton in commerce classes are maintained by using DI ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.

For Access/instantiate instance itself, say new CommerceManager() wont it lose the singleton property since its not access via container. Can i use 
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(commerceManager)) to maintain singleton ?

Comment: @rocks "CommerceManager class cannot be a Real singleton" -- in that case I don't think you have any options, except enforcing singleton use at runtime which I would **not** recommend.

Comment: @rocks Using `DependencyResolver.GetService()` is the service locator pattern which is also discouraged, especially if that means other projects now have to depend on the DI framework you're using. Perhaps the question is: why do you need to enforce other projects to use it as a singleton?